# MVC Razor - Serialize HTML elements to C# collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Good morning all!

I have the following object in my C# MVC application

```
public class FamilyMember 
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string Age { get; set; }
   public string Relationship { get; set; }
}
```

And also I have a object that contains a collection of the above class

```
public class Authorization {
   public ICollection<FamilyMember> FamilyMembers { get; set; }
}
```

Now all of this information is displayed on a View using a loop:

```
<ul class="family-list small-text" id="family-list">
@for (int i = 0; i < familySize; i++)
{
    var member = Model.FamilyMembers.ElementAt(i);
    <li class="family-member">
        <label style="display: none;" for="FirstName" class="grey-text family-label">First Name:</label>
        <input style="display: none;" type="text" class="family-member-input" id="FirstName" name="FamilyMember.FirstName" value="@member.FirstName" />
        <label style="display: none;" for="LastName" class="grey-text family-label">Last Name:</label>
        <input style="display: none;" type="text" class="family-member-input" id="LastName" name="LastName" value="@member.LastName" />
        <label style="display: none;" for="Age" class="grey-text family-label">Age:</label>
        <input style="display: none;" type="text" class="family-member-input" id="Age" name="Age" value="@member.Age" />
        <label style="display: none;" for="Relationship" class="grey-text family-label">Relationship:</label>
        <input style="display: none;" type="text" class="family-member-input" id="Relationship" name="Relationship" value="@member.Relationship" />
    </li>
}
```

Where `@familySize` is the `Count` of the FamilyMember collection.

Now there's a button on this view called `Save` that, after clicking, serializes the above list, among more input elements, using the jQuery `.serialize()` method. The output from this method is then sent to an `AJAX` call which calls out to an action method I've set up in the MVC project:

```
var saveConfirmed = function () {
    saveTransfereeAjax(transfereeForm.serialize(), saveTransfereeSuccess, saveTransfereeFailure);
};

var saveTransfereeAjax = function (data, success, error) {
    console.log(data);
    bootbox.dialog({
        message:
            '<div class="text-center"><img src="/Content/Images/load-spinner.gif" alt="loader" /> <p>Processing...</p></div>'
    });
    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        dataType: "text",
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/savetransferee",
        success: success,
        error: error
    })
};
```

Where `transfereeForm` is the form on my view that I'm looking to serialize.

And here is the action method that is being POSTed to by the `AJAX` call.

```
public IHttpActionResult Save(Authorization authorization)
{
    //process authorization
}
```

Once I hit the action method, everything in the form seems to have serialized correctly, though not the members of the `FamilyMember` collection.

Is there any specific name attributes I need to have for each `FamilyMember` object's properties that are inside my view that would allow for each to be serialized into the `FamilyMember` collection? For example:

```
<input type='text' name='FamilyMember[i].FirstName' id='FamilyMember[i].FirstName' value='@member.FirstName' />
```

Where `i` represents the current index of the `FamilyMember` collection I'm iterating through.

Comment: can you please provide us with javascript code you wrote for this ?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the Javascript code I'm using to make the `ajax`  call, and to serialize the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will get the correct ID's and names if you use the HTML helpers. Also you have to use array instead of collection:

```
 public FamilyMember[] FamilyMembers { get; set; }

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.FamilyMembers.Length; i++) { 
        <li class="family-member">
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.FamilyMembers[i].FirstName, new {style = "display:none;"})
        </li>
      }
```

This would result in code:

```
<input id="FamilyMembers_0__FirstName" name="FamilyMembers[0].FirstName" style="display:none;" type="text" value="Name0">
```

Witch would result in this serialized value: 
    FamilyMembers%5B0%5D.FirstName=Name0&FamilyMembers%5B1%5D.FirstName=Name1&FamilyMembers%5B2%5D.FirstName=Name2

Also this might be better serialized as json using serializeArray, have a look at this question: [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery)

EDIT: here is how you could do it with serializeArray and keep using iCollection

First you need to set the name correctly.

```
 @{ var i = -1;}
    <ul class="family-list small-text" id="family-list">
      @foreach (var familyMembers in Model.FamilyMembers)
      {
        i++;
        <li class="family-member">
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => familyMembers.Age, new {Name = "familyMembers[" + i + "].Age", style="display:none;" })
        </li>
      }
    </ul>
```

Then you need to serialize this as JSON, and post it as JSON

```
function objectifyForm(formArray) {//serialize data function
  var returnArray = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < formArray.length; i++){
    returnArray[formArray[i]['name']] = formArray[i]['value'];
  }
  return returnArray;
}
var data = objectifyForm($('form').serializeArray());
$.ajax({
  data: data,
  dataType: "text/json",
  type: "POST",
  url: "/api/savetransferee",
  success: success,
  error: error
});
```

Comment: When I inspect the 'Authorization` object in my action method I'm still seeing the `FamilyMembers` property as `null`.

Comment: Updated answer so that you should get more correct code.

Comment: For my purposes, `FamilyMembers` is of type `ICollection<FamilyMember>` and not `FamilyMember[]` so instead of using `Model.FamilyMembers[i]` I have to use `Model.FamilyMembers.ElementAt(i)`, which still produces just `FirstName=Joseph&LastName=Jones&Age=10&Relationship=Son&FirstName=Mary&LastName=Jones&Age=16&Relationship=Daughter&FirstName=Mike&LastName=McDonald&Age=25&Relationship=Son`.

Comment: I just changed the `ICollection<FamilyMember>` to `FamilyMember[]` and your answer worked~